# How can I input password to manage-bde -pw option via windows powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-command-prompt, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I am trying to encrypt Data volume (for example E:) with the following command:

```
manage-bde -protectors -add E: -pw
```

When I execute the above command, it will ask for the password, so I entered it. It is successfully encrypting my data volume. Now, I want to make a script to encrypt a data volume, so I need to pass the password as an argument to the above powershell command.

How can I do that? Is there any option of passing the password for manage-bde command?

Comment: Be aware that `manage-bde` is a command line executable and not a PowerShell cmdlet (although it tries to emulate PowerShell's parameter syntax) - and according to the documentation, `manage-bde` does not seem to support scripted password inputs, even the `-changepassword` context prompts for the password interactively :(

Comment: There is no option of achieving this? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working on Windows Server 2012 or newer, you can use the [BitLocker cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649829(v=wps.630).aspx):

```
Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "E:" -Password ("Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) -PasswordProtector
```

The `Add-BitLockerKeyProtector` cmdlet accepts the password in the form of a [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, which is why we pipe the plaintext "Password" to `ConvertTo-SecureString`

Comment: I am using Windows 7, is there any option of achieving the same on windows 7?

Comment: @SureshKota Sorry, the PowerShell module is not available on Windows 7 according to this [RSAT support matrix](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-client-and-windows-server-dsforum2wiki.aspx#RSAT_Platform_and_Tools_Support_Matrix)